# How to create NSIndexPath for TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, nsindexpath

I need delete row 1 of a table in a function I have defined. In order to use `deleteRowAtIndexPath` you must use an `IndexPath` with a section and row defined. How can I create an indexpath like this?

An array with the int {1} as its only member will crash; the NSLog message states that the section needs to be defined as well.

*Edit -> Code relating to cell delete:

```
    NSIndexPath *myIP = [[NSIndexPath alloc] indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myIP, nil];
//  [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:myArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
//  [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 649, accepted):

Use `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:inSection:]` to quickly create an index path.

**Edit:** In Swift 3:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: sectionIndex)
```

**Swift 5**

```
IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
```

Answer (score 129):

`indexPathForRow` is a class method!

The code should read:

```
NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] ;
```

Answer (score 18):

Obligatory answer in Swift : `NSIndexPath(forRow:row, inSection: section)`

You will notice that `NSIndexPath.indexPathForRow(row, inSection: section)` is not available in swift and you must use the first method to construct the indexPath.

Answer (score 17):

For Swift 3 it's now: `IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: sectionIndex)`